# Python [Errno 17] File exists Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, When the folder is created first time, The directory is created and the files are successfully created in that folder path. When again a new file needs to be created in the same location, I'm getting this error:

> ```
> [Errno 17] File exists: '/home/test/files/tweets/'.
> ```

Any suggestions please?

```
if len(downloadedfile) > 0:
    #insert_time=time.strftime('%Y_%-m_%-d')
    #download_path='/home/test/files/tweets/'
    #file_path= download_path+insert_time+"/"+hashes
    #print(file_path)
    now = datetime.now
    new_folder = '/home/test/files/tweets/{}'.format(now().strftime('%Y_%-m_%-d'))
    os.mkdir(new_folder, 0755 );
    folder_path = new_folder+"/"+hashes
    fo = open(folder_path,"wb")
    fo.write(downloadedfile)
    fo.close()
    print("File Downloaded")
else:
   print("File Not Downloaded")
```

Comment: You can catch the exception with `try` / `except`.

Comment: i would suggest to use os.makedirs instead with exist_ok=True param

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catch the `OSError` with a `try:except:`:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(new_folder, 0755)
except OSError:
    pass
```

This is a bit unsatisfactory, as there are other errors that this might ignore.

Comment: Note that the `errno` attribute can be tested to find the exact error.

Comment: the `errno` attribute can be tested (as per @cdarke) but this introduces an OS dependency (no guarantee that Windows, Mac, Linux, other Unixes use same error codes).

Answer (score 4):

Python > 3.2 supports the exist_ok argument:
`os.makedirs(new_diresctory, exist_ok=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to check whether the file exists or not.

> os.path.isdir()

Comment: it will return false if path is directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error when Python expects a path with the file name included but you only provide the path for the parent directory of the file you are trying to create.

For example, you give

```
/Users/yourname/Desktop
```

instead of

```
/Users/scottlydon/Desktop/newFile.txt
```